# RewriteCond HTTPS true despite http request

Tags: apache, http, https

I have the following lines of code in my enabled .conf, which should redirect the browser to google if the connection is not established through https, as far as i understand.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://google.com/ [R,L]

SSLEngine On
...
```

If the connection is made using https on the other hand, the SSLEngine kicks in and handles everything.

The issue is that SSLEngine kicks in in every case, complaining about the reqest being made without ssl.

Is there a way to interrupt the whole script execution whenever http is detected, so that the SSLEngine doesn't kick in?

I tried disabling the SSLEngine, after that the RewriteRule worked just fine.

Comment: You need two separate `VirtulHost`s in your httpd.conf: one on port 80 (without SSLEngine) and one on port 443 (with SSLEngine)

Comment: i expected that to be an answer, unfortunately i cannot split them since i do not get around http requests being submitted to that port.

Comment: Those can be any arbitrary port numbers, it is just that you can not serve both http and https from the same VirtualHost

Comment: I am bound to using the same port. Why can i not server both? As far as i got it i could redirect http to https before https even kicks in

Comment: You just can not have one port listen for both HTTP and HTTPS requests. `SSLEngine On` never "kicks in", it is read only on server startup and if it is there, that VirtualHost will accept only https

Comment: Oh, i expected it to execute the file sequentially on every request...well, thanks for that info